# Condition for when finite cylinder and sphere intersect

Tags: analytic-geometry

I feel like the answer to the following question is well known but I have not been able to find a reference to it with exception to a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393497/intersection-between-sphere-and-cylinder) and an article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere%E2%80%93cylinder_intersection).

Given $h, r, R > 0$ and $(x_0, y_0, z_0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, define
$$
C = \lbrace (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ |\ x^2 + y^2 = R^2 \text{ and } |z| \leq h \rbrace,
$$
$$
S = \lbrace (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ |\ (x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 + (z - z_0)^2 = r^2 \rbrace.
$$

What are the conditions on $h, r, R, x_0, y_0, z_0$ so that $C \cap S \neq \emptyset$?

My approach has been to substitute $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$ into $(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 + (z - z_0)^2 = r^2$ and consider slices of constant $z \in [-h, h]$. The desired intersection is empty if the intersection of the resulting circles is empty for every $z$.

I appreciate the help. Thanks!

Edit:
Some additional details to my approach.

Note if $C \cap S \neq \emptyset$, there must exist $z' \in [-h,h]$ such that
$$r^2 - (z' - z_0)^2 \geq 0$$
and
$$(R - (r^2 - (z' - z_0)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}})^2 
    \leq x_0^2 + y_0^2
    \leq (R + (r^2 - (z' - z_0)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}})^2.$$

The first inequality comes from the requirement that the sphere intersects with a plane on which the cylinder's cross sections are defined. The second inequality is the condition for two circles to intersect on the plane.

The first inequality leads to
$$
z' \in [\max(z_0-r, -h), \min(z_0+r, h)].
$$

Comment: Please be a little more careful when tagging questions in the future: you applied both "algebraic geometry" and "intersection theory", neither of which was appropriate for this question. You can read the tag description for information about whether it's appropriate - for instance, the algebraic geometry tag reads "[t]his tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry."

Comment: Find the distance between the sphere's center and the axis of the cylinder.  If this distance is less than the sum of the sphere's radius and the cylinder's radius, then....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final condition is the following: $$\begin{cases}h\ge0\\ \lvert z_0\rvert\ge h\\ (h-\lvert z_0\rvert)^2+\left(\lvert R\rvert-\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\le r^2\\ r^2\le(h+\lvert z_0\rvert)^2+\left(\lvert R\rvert+\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\end{cases}\lor\begin{cases}h> 0\\ \lvert z_0\rvert<h\\ \left\lvert \lvert R\rvert-\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right\rvert\le\lvert r\rvert\\ r^2\le(h+\lvert z_0\rvert)^2+\left(\lvert R\rvert+\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\end{cases}$$

And an interpretation of this in terms of funny segments is left to whoever may want to do so.

First, let's recall that the parametric system $$\begin{cases}c_1\le ax+by\le c_2\\ x^2+y^2=R^2\end{cases}$$ has solutions in $(x,y)$ if and only if $$\begin{cases} c_1\le \lvert R\rvert\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\c_2\ge-\lvert R\rvert\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\ c_2\ge c_1\end{cases}$$

Now, your condition is that the following system has solutions in $(x,y,z)$ \begin{align}&\begin{cases}(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2=r^2\\ x^2+y^2=R^2\\ \lvert z\rvert\le h\end{cases}\\\\\hline\\&\begin{cases}h\ge 0\\(z-z_0)^2=r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y\\ x^2+y^2=R^2\\ -h\le z\le h\\ \end{cases}\\ \\\hline\\&\begin{cases}z=z_0+\sqrt{r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y}\\(i)\begin{cases}r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y\ge0\\ \sqrt{r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y}\le h-z_0\\ \sqrt{r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y}\ge-h-z_0\\ x^2+y^2=R^2\\ h\ge 0\end{cases}\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}z=z_0-\sqrt{r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y}\\(ii)\begin{cases}r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y\ge0\\ \sqrt{r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y}\ge z_0-h\\ \sqrt{r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y}\le h+z_0\\ x^2+y^2=R^2\\ h\ge 0\end{cases}\end{cases}\end{align}

Now, it is clear that the disjunction of the two systems has solutions in $(x,y,z)$ if and only if $(i)\lor (ii)$ has solutions in $(x,y)$. Let's notice that $(ii)_{R,r,h,x_0,y_0,z_0}$ is just $(i)_{R,r,h,x_0,y_0,-z_0}$. Therefore, let's focus on $(i)$.

\begin{align}&\begin{cases}r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y\ge0\\ \sqrt{r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y}\le h-z_0\\ \sqrt{r^2-R^2-x_0^2-y_0^2+2x_0x+2y_0y}\ge-h-z_0\\ x^2+y^2=R^2\\ h\le0\end{cases}\\\\\hline\\
&\begin{cases}2x_0x+2y_0y\ge R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\ h\ge z_0\\ 2x_0x+2y_0y\le(h-z_0)^2+R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\ z_0\le- h\\ 2x_0x+2y_0y\ge(h+z_0)^2+R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\ x^2+y^2=R^2\\ h\ge0\end{cases}\lor\begin{cases}2x_0x+2y_0y\ge R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\ h\ge z_0\\ 2x_0x+2y_0y\le(h-z_0)^2+R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\ z_0>-h\\ x^2+y^2=R^2\\ h\ge0\end{cases}\\ \\\hline\\&\begin{cases}z_0\le- h\\ 2x_0x+2y_0y\le(h-z_0)^2+R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\  2x_0x+2y_0y\ge(h+z_0)^2+R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\ x^2+y^2=R^2\\ h\ge0\end{cases}\lor\begin{cases}-h<z_0\le h\\ 2x_0x+2y_0y\ge R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\ 2x_0x+2y_0y\le(h-z_0)^2+R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\ x^2+y^2=R^2\\ h>0\end{cases}\end{align}

By the previous lemma about intersection of a circle with a stripe, the disjoint systems above have solutions in $(x,y)$ if and only if $$\begin{cases}z_0\le- h\\ (h+z_0)^2+R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\le2\lvert R\rvert\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\\  -2\lvert R\rvert\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\le(h-z_0)^2+R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\ (h-z_0)^2\ge(h+z_0)^2\\ h\ge0\end{cases}\lor\begin{cases}-h<z_0\le h\\ 2\lvert R\rvert\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\ge R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\ -2\lvert R\rvert\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}<(h-z_0)^2+R^2+x_0^2+y_0^2-r^2\\ (h-z_0)^2\ge0\\ h>0\end{cases}$$ And the latter may be simplified to $$\begin{cases}z_0\le- h\\ (h+z_0)^2+\left(\rvert R\rvert-\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\le r^2\\  r^2\le(h-z_0)^2+\left(\lvert R\rvert+\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\\  h\ge0\end{cases}\lor\begin{cases}-h<z_0\le h\\ \left\lvert\lvert R\rvert-\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right\rvert\le \lvert r\rvert\\ r^2\le(h-z_0)^2+\left(\lvert R\rvert+\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\\  h>0\end{cases}$$

Let's call these two conditions $(ia)$ and $(ib)$.
As it was remarked before, $(ii)$ is just $(i)$ with parameter $-z_0$ instead of $z_0$, therefore it has solutions in $(x,y)$ if and only if
$$\begin{cases}z_0\ge h\\ (h-z_0)^2+\left(\rvert R\rvert-\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\le r^2\\  r^2\le(h+z_0)^2+\left(\lvert R\rvert+\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\\  h\ge0\end{cases}\lor\begin{cases}-h\le z_0< h\\ \left\lvert\lvert R\rvert-\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right\rvert\le \lvert r\rvert\\ r^2\le(h+z_0)^2+\left(\lvert R\rvert+\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\\  h> 0\end{cases}$$

Let's call these two conditions $(iia)$ and $(iib)$. The original system has solutions if and only if $(ia)\lor(ib)\lor(iia)\lor(iib)$. Now, notice that $(ia)\lor (iia)$ is equivalent to $$\begin{cases}\lvert z_0\rvert\ge h\\ (h-\lvert z_0\rvert)^2+\left(\rvert R\rvert-\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\le r^2\\  r^2\le(h+\lvert z_0\rvert)^2+\left(\lvert R\rvert+\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\\  h\ge0\end{cases}$$
Moreover, $((ib)\land z_0=h)\Rightarrow (iia)$ and $((iib)\land z_0=-h)\Rightarrow (ia)$. Therefore, $(ia)\lor (iia)$ is equivalent to $(ia)\lor(iia)\lor((ib)\land z_0=h)\lor((iib)\land z_0=-h)$. All that is left is the part $((ib)\land z\ne h)\lor((iib)\land z\ne -h)$. Notice that this is equivalent to $$\begin{cases}\lvert z_0\rvert<h\\ \left\lvert\lvert R\rvert-\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right\rvert\le \lvert r\rvert\\ r^2\le\max((h+z_0)^2,(h-z_0)^2)+\left(\lvert R\rvert+\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right)^2\\  h>0\end{cases}$$

Since $h\ge0$, we have that $\max((h+z_0)^2,(h-z_0)^2)=(h+\lvert z_0\rvert)^2$. This concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Find the cross sections of both surfaces with the plane $z=z_0$. We can geometrically see that an intersection between these 2 cross section is the necessary condition for intersection between $C$ and $S$.

So we want to find the conditions such that $x^2+y^2=R^2$ and $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$ intersect. We can see that there is an intersection when the distance between the two centers is less than or equal to the sum of the radii. This implies that $\boxed{\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}\leq R+r}$.

Answer (score 0):

Forget initially about $h$.

Consider the plane $\pi$ containing the cylinder axis and the center of the sphere, and project the solids there: you see a generatrix of the cylinder crossing a great circle of the sphere.
Then take a projection on the $x,y$ plane: you see the intersection of two circles.
You realize that till the two projections intersecate in  $\pi$ so do the solids.

Therefore you can reduce the problem in 2D, since it has a cylindrical symmetry, and find the two point of intersection in $z$. Then compare $[z_1, z_2]$ with $[-h,h]$

Comment: To clarify, the plane $\pi$ is determined by the vectors $x_0 \hat{x} + y_{0}\hat{y} + z_{0}\hat{z}$ and $\hat{z}$ plus the origin? Also, the projection on the $x,y$ plane is the $z=0$ plane, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The distance from the axis of the cylinder $(x=0, y = 0)$ to the center of the sphere must be less than the radius of the sphere plus the radius of the cylinder.

$R + r < \sqrt {x_0^2 + y_0}^2$